# Access violation when accessing vector element's member function

Tags: c++, function, vector, bitmap, access-violation

I am coding an MFC applcation using VS2012.

I have a vector of `Bitmap*`, I insert elements in a for loop, and then, if I try to access some element's function outside the loop it will give me an access violation.

The strange thing is if I try to access it inside the loop, it works just fine.

In both examples `m_VectorImageNames` is already filled with some image files paths, it is not the problem.

The following code gives the access violation (at the last line):

```
std::vector<Bitmap *> vectorImages;

for (int i = 0; i < nImages; i++) 
{
    Bitmap img(m_VectorImageNames[i]);

    vectorImages.push_back(&img);
}

int imgWidth= vectorImages[0]->GetWidth();
```

If I put the `GetWidth` inside the loop, it returns the correct value:

```
std::vector<Bitmap *> vectorImages;

for (int i = 0; i < nImages; i++) 
{
    Bitmap img(m_VectorImageNames[i]);

    vectorImages.push_back(&img);

    int imgWidth= vectorImages[0]->GetWidth();
}
```

I have tried a few things already, with no success:

- Initializing the vector with the size it will have and then inserting each bitmap in its corresponding position (with hope that it was an allocation problem).
- Looping using iterators
- Making the vector a class member variable

Does anyone have a clue of what may be happening?

Comment: You need to be aware of the lifetime of your objects. Your `Bitmap`s are destroyed at the end of the iteration of the loop. You then have pointers to already destroyed objects.

Comment: " vectorImagenes.push_back(&img); " is that supposed to be vectorImages.push_back(&img) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BitMap object `img` is defined on the stack inside the loop. The pointer to `img` is pushed into the vector. Then the memory storage that the pointer elements point to in the vector is lost once the loop has terminated.

Use `new` (the operator for dynamic memory allocation) to store the bitmaps.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nImages; i++) 
{
    Bitmap *img = new BitMap(m_VectorImageNames[i]);
    vectorImages.push_back(img);
    ...
}
```

Possibly better (instead of using raw pointers) would be to use a memory-managed pointer such as `std::shared_ptr`. This depends on your requirements.

Comment: Not really. `m_VectorImages` was filled before the loop.

Comment: @suspectus Yes, and hence "the memory storage for the elements held in the vector" is *not* lost. The objects to which the elements point are lost.

Comment: Okay thanks, I get your point. The question now is what do I do? I can't use a `vector<Bitmap>` because it gives me a problem in the initialization. Would it be the solution?

If not what should I do in order to not getting the bitmaps destroyed?

Comment: @suspectus I had to comment these lines at the top of the source file, which didn't allow me to use `new`:

`#ifdef _DEBUG`
`#define new DEBUG_NEW`
`endif`

But now it seems to work properly.

Thank you very much :)